# SQL script to execute on all tables in database

Tags: sql-server, automation, dynamic-sql

Please assist with ideas on how I can make this script dynamic to be able to loop through all tables in a database and do the same thing. The script renames a database with suffix '_Old' then crates a new database. It then copies tables into the new database and moves the data into the newly created table.

I am not good with scripting so I have no idea how to tackle this challenge. Ay help is welcome.

```
USE Test
GO
```

-- 1. RENAME CURRENT TABLE

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Customer', 'Customer_Old'
```

-- 2. CREATE NEW TABLE

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
 [co_cde] [smallint] NULL,
 [cust_no] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [customer_key] [bigint] NULL,
 [UCN] [bigint] NULL,
 [main_system] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
 [premium_model] [varchar](4) NULL,
 [prim_ofcr_ind] [varchar](5) NULL,
 [prim_ofcr_ind0] [varchar](5) NULL,
 [current_model] [varchar](5) NULL,
 [new_model] [varchar](5) NULL,
 [legal_type] [varchar](200) NULL,
 [legal_name] [varchar](255) NULL,
 [fullname] [varchar](85) NULL,
 [title] [varchar](200) NULL,
 [initials] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [firstname] [varchar](100) NULL,
 [surname] [varchar](100) NULL,
 [id_no] [bigint] NULL,
 [date_of_birth] [date] NULL,
 [age] [smallint] NULL,
 [deceased_date] [date] NULL,
 [cust_rec_open_date] [date] NULL,
 [cust_type] [varchar](2) NULL,
 [customer_type] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [source_cust_type] [varchar](40) NULL,
 [cust_stat] [varchar](12) NULL,
 [gender] [varchar](1) NULL,
 [race] [varchar](10) NULL,
 [email_addr] [varchar](124) NULL,
 [cell_no] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [cntct_tel_no] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [pers_tel_no] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [bus_tel_no] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [pri_seg] [varchar](3) NULL,
 [pri_sub_seg] [varchar](3) NULL,
 [income_amt] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
 [income_estimate] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
 [mth_cr_turnover] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
 [premium_income] [numeric](21, 2) NULL,
 [zip_cde] [varchar](27) NULL,
 [branch_cde] [smallint] NULL,
 [rsk_cat_cde] [varchar](1) NULL,
 [grad_type] [varchar](9) NULL,
 [high_edu_lvl] [varchar](9) NULL,
 [qual_speciality] [varchar](9) NULL,
 [kyc_ind] [varchar](3) NULL,
 [fr_rating] [varchar](9) NULL,
 [bank_relationship] [varchar](6) NULL,
 [bank_relationship_type] [varchar](12) NULL,
 [med_pages] [smallint] NULL,
 [fast_mover] [smallint] NULL,
 [hypersegmentation] [smallint] NULL,
 [income_model] [varchar](25) NULL,
 [nav_income_band] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [VSI] [smallint] NULL,
 [main_banked] [smallint] NULL,
 [household_key] [bigint] NULL,
 [household_relationship] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [household_category] [varchar](25) NULL,
 [mkt_cell] [varchar](3) NULL,
 [mkt_sms] [varchar](3) NULL,
 [mkt_phone] [varchar](3) NULL,
 [mkt_post] [varchar](3) NULL,
 [mkt_email] [varchar](3) NULL,
 [mkt_fnb] [varchar](3) NULL,    
 [qpwr] [bit] NULL,
 [qpwf] [bit] NULL,
 [qpcf] [bit] NULL,
 [qpbf] [bit] NULL,
 [qpwfs] [bit] NULL,
 [qpcfs] [bit] NULL,
 [qpbfs] [bit] NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```

-- 3. GET COLUMNS FROM CURRENT TABLE (dbo.Customer_Old)

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl_current') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tbl_current
 CREATE TABLE #tbl_current (id TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, column_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #tbl_current
SELECT column_name  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'Customer_Old' and table_schema = 'dbo'
```

-- 4. GET COLUMNS FROM NEW TABLE (dbo.Customer)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl_new') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tbl_new

CREATE TABLE #tbl_new (id TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, column_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #tbl_new SELECT column_name  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'Customer' and table_schema = 'dbo'
```

-- 5. BUILD INSERT AND SELECT STATEMENT

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#final_columns') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #final_columns
  SELECT a.column_name AS old_col,
  b.column_name AS new_col,
   CASE WHEN a.column_name IS NULL     
  THEN b.column_name

 WHEN b.column_name IS NOT NULL THEN a.column_name
  WHEN b.column_name IS NULL THEN NULL         
 END AS new_columns,
  CASE 
  WHEN a.column_name IS NULL THEN 'NULL AS ' + b.column_name
  WHEN b.column_name IS NOT NULL THEN b.column_name +' AS '+ a.column_name
  WHEN b.column_name IS NULL       THEN NULL        
  END 
 AS col_sel   INTO #final_columns    
   FROM #tbl_current a
  FULL JOIN #tbl_new b
  ON a.column_name = b.column_name

 DECLARE @rowcnt TINYINT, @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl_final') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tbl_final
  CREATE TABLE #tbl_final (id TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, column_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, column_insert VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #tbl_final
SELECT new_columns AS column_name,
col_sel     AS column_insert
FROM #final_columns
WHERE new_columns IS NOT NULL

SET @rowcnt = @@rowcount 

IF @rowcnt > 0
 BEGIN
DECLARE @i TINYINT = 1, 
    @tbl_columns VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @ins_columns VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

WHILE @i <= @rowcnt
BEGIN
IF @i = 1 
BEGIN
    SET @tbl_columns = (SELECT column_name   FROM #tbl_final WHERE id = @i)
    SET @ins_columns = (SELECT column_insert FROM #tbl_final WHERE id = @i)
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SET @tbl_columns = @tbl_columns + ', ' + (SELECT column_name   
FROM #tbl_final WHERE id = @i)
    SET @ins_columns = @ins_columns + ', ' + (SELECT column_insert 
FROM #tbl_final WHERE id = @i)
END
SET @i = @i + 1
END

PRINT @tbl_columns
PRINT @ins_columns   
 END

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO dbo.Customer ('+ @tbl_columns +')
    SELECT '+ @ins_columns +'
 FROM dbo.Customer_Old   
   '
 PRINT @sql
 --EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Why not Backup -> Rename -> Restore? That would seem a far better solution. Personally, I would actually do Backup -> Restore (with a different name) -> Rename Old -> Rename New. The reason there is that limits the downtime as much as possible.

Comment: @larnu Why not make that an answer.

Comment: I'm *hoping* that the OP has a "good" reason as to why they can't do it that way, @Ben and could explain why. If not, then yes I'll certainly post a script to backup and restore the database, and rename them.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will run this past the person who requested this. I think that is a better option for a person who doesn't know a lot about scripting :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use SELECT INTO statement. Build up your table names in a cursor, which loops the system.objects or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. It will use the same column names and types when you keep the original name (no alias).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017